# collection_select with has_many and belongs_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, associations

I have a simple scaffolded project to test this feature out.
It has two models, `User` model and `Fruit` model.

I'm trying to implement a feature where user can choose an existing fruit using collection_select from the database and then list it alongside his name and also be able to query for users based on the fruits (EG: List all Users with Apples)

**Note:** I filled up the Fruit table with sample fruits to test it out. Not sure if it's the correct way but I got the collection_select to work.

**My issue**

The issue is two-fold. One that fruits are not saved to particular user (even though the params has has the neccessary attributes) and second if i try to call `User.fruits.name` i get "Fruits" and `User.fruits` give me an unexpected result of "    #".

I've been reading up and trying solutions on my main project which has exact structure, but it doesnt seem to work. I'm also seeking alternatives, if there's a more efficient version.

Here are the code snippets:

**params hash**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :fruits
end
```

**users/index.html.erb**

```
<p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>

<h1>Listing Users</h1>

<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th colspan="3"></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <% @users.each do |user| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= user.name %></td>
        <<td><%= user.fruits%></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Show', user %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_user_path(user) %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', user, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>

<br>

<%= link_to 'New User', new_user_path %>
```

**users/_form.html.erb**

```
<%= form_for(@user) do |f| %>
  <% if @user.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@user.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this user from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @user.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
        <li><%= message %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :name %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :name %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :fruits %>
    <%= f.collection_select(:fruits, Fruit.all, :id, :name, :include_blank => "Please select") %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

**users_controller**

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_user, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /users
  # GET /users.json
  def index
    @users = User.all
  end

  # GET /users/1
  # GET /users/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /users/new
  def new
    @fruit = Fruit.new
    @user = User.new
  end

  # GET /users/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /users
  # POST /users.json
  def create
    debugger
    @user = User.new(user_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @user.save
        format.html { redirect_to @user, notice: 'User was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @user }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /users/1
  # PATCH/PUT /users/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @user.update(user_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @user, notice: 'User was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @user }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /users/1
  # DELETE /users/1.json
  def destroy
    @user.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to users_url, notice: 'User was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_user
      @user = User.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def user_params
      params.require(:user).permit(:name, :fruit_ids)
    end
end
```

**fruit.rb**

```
class Fruit < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end
```

**user.rb**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :fruits
end
```

**schema.rb**

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20151215214130) do 

create_table "fruits", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.integer  "user_id"
  end

  create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

end
```

I'm honestly at my wits end. I feel like i'm missing something very basic and obvious.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like theres a misunderstanding in what `user.fruits` is.  The fruits collection on user is a essentially an array of Fruit objects.  You don't want to do this

```
= @user.fruits
```

or this

```
= User.fruits # I don't think this method on the `User` class exists
```

Maybe you want to do this

```
= @user.fruits.map{|f| f.name}
```

or this

```
= render @user.fruits
```

The latter will call the _fruit.erb partial and render based on the code in that.

```
# _fruit.erb
= fruit.name
```

To set user.fruits, you will need to set it in the db.  There are two ways you can do this

1) Send the fruit ids to the user#fruit_ids= method

```
# for example
@user.fruit_ids = [1,2,3,4]
```

2) Set the user_id on the fruit object

```
@fruit.user = @user # or @fruit.user_id = @user.id
```

It looks like you want to pass the fruit_ids to the user.  To do this, a common way to do this is to set up a grid of checkboxes.  They need to have the param name "user[fruit_ids][]".  The extra [] on the end is to indicate to rails that it is an array.

Another way to do this, and maybe what you intended, is to set up a multiple select box

```
<%= f.collection_select(:fruit_ids, Fruit.all, :id, :name, { :include_blank => "Please select")}, { :multiple => true } %>
```

In the controller, make sure the strong params accepts this param - the syntax is like this

```
params.require(:user).permit(:name, :fruit_ids => [])
```

Then you can pass the array of ids to the controller and it will set the user_id correctly on all the fruit objects.

Lastly - I'm not sure what your doing is what you mean to do.  The has_many, belongs_to relation is often a parent-child relation.  I don't see the case where you'd set up fruit ahead of time and then assign it to user.  Maybe it's just an exercise?  Another way to set the user_id on fruit - you can create fruit under a user.

```
@user.fruits << Fruit.new(:name => "Orange")
```

If instead you want to have a fruit object (where there is only one Orange or one Apple in the system) where the user can favorite it or select it without editing the fruit record, you would do this.

Have another table representing favorite fruit that would look like so:

```
class UserFruit < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :fruit

end
```

With this model, you'd be able to represent ownership or favorite fruit and reuse a fruit object so other users could also favorite or own it.

You would set it up like so

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :user_fruits, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :fruits, :through => :user_fruits
end
```

and change fruit.rb

```
class Fruit < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :user_fruits, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :users, :through => :user_fruits
end
```

You can still use the `@user.fruit_ids=(array)` method to create/destroy the join table records, your form for user wouldn't really change at all.

And don't forget the migration

```
create_table :user_fruits do |t|
  t.references :user
  t.references :fruit
end
```

Comment: It appears that i certainly was misunderstanding it and you helped out tremendously. I appreciate your throughout answer. Regarding the association, i want to have the predetermined list of fruits and i don't want user to add more, i want him to be able to choose from the existing rows of fruits. Is it the right approach or is it better to have some other way of having users chose those? I want to be able to find those users by their fruits so i figured having a seperate model with prepopulated rows is the way to go.

Comment: regarding the pluralization of `:fruit_ids` is that result of Rails convention over configuration? Can i refer to that as :fruit_id since it's an array anyway? I'd appreciate if you could touch on that (Even though it might be a topic for another question)

Comment: Yes - rails gives you that method with has_many - http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-has_many.  It sounds like you want the join table - that way the fruit records won't change.  You can have many user_fruits that represent the relationship between user and fruit.  You could, for example, also have a rating, that would go on user_fruit.  I'll add more to the answer for how to set up a join table.